# auto complete in angular6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have auto complete working for my angular app, I have `ngfor` which iterates over array of object, I pass the index of the object array to a function to perform some operations.

Here is the code I tried

**template.html**

```html
  <mat-form-field >
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async);index as i" [value] ="option">
           {{option.name}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>
```

**typescript**

```
  onCustomerChange(i) {
    console.log("called" + " "+i); // it always shows i = 0 no matter what I select in drop down
    this.customer.customerNumber = this.customers[i].AccountID;
    this.customer.customerName = this.customers[i].AccountName;
    this.topToolBarService.setCustomer(this.customer);
    this.topToolBarService.sendCustomer(this.customer);
  }
```

[image]

I select 1 or 2 I always see 0 is passed is passed. My question is how to pass value of iterator correctly?

Comment: Where you use `onCustomerChange(i)` ?

Comment: onCustomerChange(i) is called when click event happens on the template

Comment: show the implementation of your click eventlistener...

Answer (score 0):

Class file:

```
   ngOnInit() {
           this.customerFilterControl.valueChanges.subscribe((res)=>{
                console.log(res);
                this.onCustomerChange(res);
            });
          }
```

Try this and pick value from `res`